# How to prevent overlapping of draggable elements in html

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have created a text box in which I am dragging dynamically created div's. But they are overlapping if i put the div on other dropped div. I have to arrange them vertically. In jQuery i found many solutions but I need in plain javaScript. Please help me out and suggest.

The html that i have used:

```
<div id="area1" align="center" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>
```

The CSS that I have used:

```
#area1 {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:240px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #A485D8;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: A "javascript" approach would involve rewriting the functionality already provided by jQuery. What is wrong with just using jQuery instead?

Comment: yeah. I am newbie. so didn't had any idea at start. now cant change it

Comment: A question asked 4 years ago. still not answered. Nowhere i found a good solution for this problem. HTML5 drag drop with javascript is disaster, i think. An element with `draggable="true"` is getting dropped in to another draggable element eventhough the latter have neither `ondrop` nor `ondragover` events set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an element with attribute `draggable="true"`, is getting dropped to a similar (draggable) element.

It seems that somehow the same function for `ondrop` event is applied to the draggable elements also.

To avoid this, You should **add some conditions in the function that is called for `ondrop` event**. The following is an example.

```
<div id="area1" align="center" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ></div>

function drop(ev) 
{
if(ev.target.className=='into' || ev.target.className=='options_list')
    {
    var incoming_id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("incoming_choice")
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(incoming_id));
    }
}
```

In my case, i want the draggable elements to get dropped only into an element whose `className` is either `'options_list'` or `'into'`. It should not get dropped into another draggable. The `className` of draggables in my code was `'match_choice'`. Similarly, you may use `id` instead of `className` for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

This is just raw code. I haven't tested it. But it might help:

```
#area1 *
{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```